# Python 32-bit development on 64-bit Windows

Tags: python, windows

Is it possible to install 32-bit Python (2.7 series) on Windows 7/8 64-bit to develop 32-bit applications?  I'm sure the answer is yes but be good to get confirmation.

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm running both right now.

Comment: Yes, and you can install multiple instances of Python (Python2.7 32bit, Python2.6 32bit, Python3.1 64bit) on the same machine, no problem.

Comment: Besides I would prefer 32bit Python on a 64bit OS because there are few libraries which are not 64bit compatible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install almost any 32 bit software on 64 bit Windows because it has a built-in 32 bit emulator.

If you are going to use a 32 bit Python, make sure all the libraries you use are 32 bit too.

Comment: Many thanks for the confirmation.  A follow-on question - has anyone used multiple virtualenv's to develop 32-bit in one and 64-bit in another?

Comment: I can't say I have. You should open a new question and I'm sure you'll find an answer.

Comment: Just found out: install the different python versions in different directories and tell virtualenv which one to use. Best ...