# 64-bit Python on 32 Bit Windows?

Tags: python, windows, 32bit-64bit

Is it possible to run 64-bit Python on 32-bit Windows?

I have been working with 32-bit Python, but discovered that I need the extra memory for something. Is it possible to install/use 64-bit PYthon on a 32 bit copy of Windows? I've verified that all of the packages I need are available for 64-bit Python, but I am less familiar with compatibility

I have found various answers to the opposite question (running 32 bit Python on a 64 bit OS) like the following: [Python 32-bit development on 64-bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897268/python-32-bit-development-on-64-bit-windows) but nothing on this specific question

Comment: No. 32bit software can run on 64bit systems (albeit not as efficiently), but not vice versa. You can't run 64bit software on a 32bit system because there aren't enough bits. You can't create it from thin air.

Comment: Well, X86-64 software can't run directly on a x86 OS. There are a few platforms that support running 64-bit software on a 32-bit OS, but x86 isn't one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

You can run 32bit applications on 64bit Windows, but not the other way around.